# Synchronized keyword doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
package threadShareResource1;

public class NonSynchro1 {
    private int sum = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NonSynchro1 n = new NonSynchro1();
        n.task();
        System.out.println(n.getSum());
    }

    public synchronized void sumAddOne(){
        sum++;
    }

    public void task(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sumAddOne();
                }
            }).start();

        /*  try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   */
        }
    }
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Without the commented part of code, the program has data corruption, which is not 100 every time I run it. But I thought the synchronized keyword should acquires a lock on the sumAddOne method, which is the critical region of my program, allowing one thread accessing this method every time.

I've try to use ExecutorService as well, but it doesn't give 100 all the runs.

```
public void task(){
    ExecutorService s = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        s.execute(new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sumAddOne();
            }
        }));
    }
    s.shutdown();

    while(!s.isTerminated()){}
}
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To test when 100 thread accessing a common variable using synchronization. The result should be 100 at all the runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Task(), you start 100 threads (which is a lot) and each one is to add 1 to sum.

But when Task is done all you know is that 100 threads are in some process of having started. You don't block before calling println(), so how do you know all the threads have completed?

The sleep probably "prevents the corruption" just because it gives the system time to finish launching all the threads.

Beyond that you are using Synchronized correctly. Any place multiple threads may write to the same variable you need it and, in general (simplifying), you don't need it if you are only reading.

Comment: you are completely right, when i used `ExecutorService`, i forgot to use `synchronized`, that's why the result doesn't come right. So problem is the same you described, thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome Wesley. It looks like this is just demo code for learning, but just in case, I want to point out that 100 threads is *a lot* and shouldn't be used in production code. You can easily exhaust a machine's threads. In general, you work with 1 or "a few" threads or move to thread pools if you need more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Answer (score 3):

Synchronised keyword is used correctly, the problem is that you are not waiting for the threads to finish. Here is a possible solution:

```
public class NonSynchro1 {

    private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    private int sum = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NonSynchro1 n = new NonSynchro1();
        n.task();
        System.out.println(n.getSum());
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public synchronized void sumAddOne() {
        sum++;
    }

    public void task() {
        List<Callable<Object>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            callables.add(() -> {
                sumAddOne();
                return null;
            });
        }

        List<Future<Object>> futures;
        try {
            futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        futures.forEach(future -> {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

}
```

First we create a list of callables - a list of functions that will be executed in parallel.

Then we invoke them on the executor service. `newCachedThreadPool` I have used here, by default has 0 threads, it will create as many as necessary to execute all passed callables, the threads will be killed after being idle for a minute.

Finally, in the for-each loop we resolve all futures. `get()` call will block until the function was executed by the executor service. It will also throw exception if it was thrown inside the function (without calling `get()` you would not see such exception at all).

Also, it is a good idea to shutdown the executor service when you want to terminate the program gracefully. In this case, it is just `executorService.shutdown()` at the end of main method. If you don't do this, the program will terminate after a minute when idle threads are killed. However, if different executor service, threads might not be killed when idle, in which case the program would never terminate.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed Wesley, I just want to point out that this guy's strategy is very good, because it uses a thread pool instead of managing threads directly.

Comment: You should probably call `shutdown` on that `ExecutorService`

Comment: @PaulBoddington It depends on how it is actually used. I assumed that `task()` method will be called multiple times  (possibly for different instances of this class) and executor service will be reused. That's why it's static.

Comment: Well as it stands you've provided a complete example of a program that doesn't terminate normally. If my use of `while` should have come with a health warning, so should this.

Comment: This program does terminate normally. After a minute all threads will be killed. I think that how the `task()` method is used is outside the scope of this question. But you are right, it is a good idea to call `shutdown` somewhere. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Yeah you're right it does terminate after a while. Good answer.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Alternatively, instead of calling shutdown, we can set `ThreadFactory` and set threads to be daemons

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness sake: Here's a solution showing how the original program can be made to wait for all threads to finish by [joining](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) them:

```
        for (Thread t : n.task())
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

which requires `task` to return the threads it creates. In this case we don't need to complicate things with caching managers or collections: a simple array will do. Here's the complete class:

```
public class TestSynchro1 {
    private int sum = 0;

    public synchronized void sumAddOne() {
        sum++;
    }

    public Thread[] task(int n) {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            (threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sumAddOne();
                }
            })).start();
        }
        return threads;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestSynchro1 n = new TestSynchro1();
        for (Thread t : n.task(100))
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println(n.sum);
    }
}
```